# How to enforce function calling convention via an interface when using base classes

Tags: c#, generics

I am looking to create a `BaseClass<TResponse, TRequest> where TRequest IsWorkable` with functionality to transit `IsWorkable` within the flow.

My hang-up is how to enforce descendants of `BaseClass` to adhere to an Interface that enforces a function call convention on the base class without having to declare the interface on all descendants of the base class, that is, I want to avoid having to decorate all descendants of `BaseClass` with `class NewClass : BaseClass<TResponse, TRequest>, IBase<TResponse, TRequest>`.

I would prefer `NewClass : BaseClass<NewRequest, NewResponse>` instead.

**Confusing edit**
Here is the base class definition and can I somehow project the interface from the base clas onto the superclass?

```
BaseClass<TResponse, TRequest>, IBaseClass<TResponse, TRequest> where TRequest IsWorkable
```

Comment: Why can't `BaseClass` implement `IBase`?

Comment: @D Stanley - It can, however, NewClass does not get that warning that it does not implement xxx due to the fact that it has been implemented in base.

Comment: Because it does (interface implementations are inherited). If you want to ensure that each base class has a concrete implementation different from the base then make them `abstract`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show a [mcve] - to make it easier for people to visualise what you are trying to do.

Comment: If derived classes have to implement an interface method, then it should be marked as `abstract` in the base class. If a derived class an optionally override it, then it should be marked as `virtual` in the base class.

Comment: @D Stanley - I typed quicker than I could think. I am trying to see if it is possible to implement an interface in a base class and make it enforceable in descendants.

Comment: So, it seems not possible to enforce a descendant class to adhere to a base class interface, even when the base class does not fulfill the methods. I am going to mark the answer of Victor Procure as correct as he turned me on to a way to dumb down the interface and still make it enforceable in a way

Comment: The correct way of enforcing it is `abstract` implementations of the interface in the base class, as already explained. That's what he provided in his example.

Comment: @RossBush Sure it is - make the base class methods `abstract` so that the descendants have to provide an implementation. That's what the answer you accepted did so I'm not clear what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to do this quite a bit for things like Converters in WPF, which share a lot of core functionality.

My general methodology is to generalize the base class enough, that I can create a new method with reduced parameters and mark it as `abstract` and then call that method from the base class. Which means anything inheriting will have to implement the new method.

BaseConverter.cs:

```
public class BaseConverter<TConvert, TConvertBack> : IValueConverter
{
    protected CultureInfo CurrentCulture { get; set;}

    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CurrentCulture = culture;

        // Generic methods to check types and conversions....
        var typedValue = (TConvert)value;

        return Convert(typedValue, targetType, parameters);
     }

     protected abstract Convert(TConvert value, Type targetType, object parameters);

     /// Implement rest of interfaces/generic
}
```

StringToBooleanConverter.cs:

```
public class StringToBooleanConverter : BaseConverter<string, bool>
{
    protected override object Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameters)
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        // Convert string to boolean and assign to retVal
        return retVal;
    }
}
```